# How do you handle a click on an SKSpriteNode WITHOUT using UIKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am using swift playgrounds on a mac and I chose the macOS option to make the application. I made an SKSpriteNode into an image an is set `skNodeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` However I can't use UIKit so it doesn't allow me to use the usual `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`

is there anyway I can get a clicked node with cocoa or any other framework?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, `SKSpriteNode` inherits from `NSResponder`. You can override methods like `mouseDown(with:NSEvent), mouseUp, mouseMoved`, etc.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsresponder).

Comment: does it have to be overriden?